# Remove columns from CSV Batch file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I'm trying to remove all columns in a csv file except columns 2, 3, 5, and 11

I'm having trouble with column 11.

This is my batch file:

```
@Echo off 
(for /f "delims=" %%A in (test.csv) do Call :Split %%A
) > test_New.csv
goto :Eof
:Split
Echo(%2,%3,%5,%11
```

It works apart from column 11 which returns column 1.

I've tried %11% but does not work either.

Thanks

Comment: Batch does not support numerical (positional) parameters greater than 9 (%0 to %9).

Comment: You might find [SS64 on `FOR`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to be useful.

Comment: Do `shift /6` in order within `:Split` to, well, shift the 11th parameter to the 9th position, so you can access it with `%9`…

Comment: Why would you not use the capability of the `FOR /F` command to split apart the line? `"tokens=2,3,5,11 delims=,"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already said, Batch doesn't support positional parameters greater than 9. While there are ways around that (`shift /n` comes to mind), a much better way of handling situations like these is to use a `tokens` option for `for /f`:

```
@echo off

(
    for /f "tokens=2,3,5,11 delims=," %%i in (test.csv) do echo:%%i,%%j,%%k,%%l
) >"test_New.csv"
```

Each token causes an additional variable name to be allocated, thus the first token (#2) becomes `%%i`, the second (#3) `%%j` and so on. See `for /?` for further details.

Comment: Thats great, thanks!
I'm now trying to add a few more and reorder the columns.

I've put `tokens=2,3,5,11,6` but it is printing as 2,3,5,6,11 in the new csv. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes @RowleyCory-Wright, use [[tag:powershell]], which has built-in support for csv files!

Comment: @RowleyCory-Wright Token numbers are automatically sorted, so in your case `tokens=2,3,5,6,11` needs to be used like: `echo:%%i,%%j,%%k,%%m,%%l` (notice how I've switched `m` and `l`).

Comment: @RowleyCory-Wright If you're satisfied with this answer, could I ask you to mark it as accepted?